# In Load Test - "The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null"

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, load-testing

when we are debugging below code with single user it is working fine. But while we tried to run Load test when user count goes more than 30 we are getting 
"The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type." exception.

This is code snippet where we are getting exception.

```
  profile.AccessRights = (
                from t in entities.Opportunities
                join x in entities.OpportunityWorkloadGroups on t.OpportunityId equals x.OpportunityId into oppworkloads
                from ow in oppworkloads.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join m in entities.OpportunityWorkloads on ow.OpportunityWorkloadGroupId equals m.OpportunityWorkloadGroupId into oppworkloadmodules
                from om in oppworkloadmodules.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join y in entities.OpportunityUsers on om.OpportunityWorkloadId equals y.OpportunityWorkloadId into users
                from ou in users.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where (((t.LookupOpportunityStatu.Name.Equals(Constants.EstimationStatusCompletedName) || t.LookupOpportunityStatu.Name.Equals(Constants.OpportunityStatusDiscardedName)
                || t.LookupOpportunityStatu.Name.Equals(OSEConstants.OpportunityStatusCompletedWithDiscards)) && !t.IsRestricted) ? true : ou.User.Alias == null ? true : ou.User.Alias == alias)
                select new Microsoft.OneEstimator.DataAccess.Entities.AccessRights()
                {
                    MasterUserId = userId,
                    MasterUserRole = roleName,
                    OpportunityId = t.OpportunityId,
                    IsOpportunityOwner = t.OpportunityOwner == userId ? true : false,
                    IsRestricted = t.IsRestricted,
                    StatusName = t.LookupOpportunityStatu.Name,
                    OpportunityWorkloadId = ow.OpportunityWorkloads.Any(m => m.OpportunityWorkloadGroupId == ow.OpportunityWorkloadGroupId) ? ow.OpportunityWorkloads.FirstOrDefault(m => m.OpportunityWorkloadGroupId == ow.OpportunityWorkloadGroupId).OpportunityWorkloadId : 0,
                    EstimationId = ow.OpportunityWorkloadGroupId == null ? 0 : ow.IsActive == false ? 0 : ow.OpportunityWorkloadGroupId,
                    RoleName = ou.Role == null ? string.Empty : ou.User.Alias == alias ? ou.Role.RoleName : string.Empty,
                    HasRightsForWA = ow.WorkloadGroupVersion != null ? entities.WorkloadGroupUsers.Any(y => y.WorkloadGroupId == ow.WorkloadGroupVersion.WorkloadGroup.WorkloadGroupId && y.UserId == userId && y.Role.RoleName.Equals(OSEConstants.Estimator)) : true,
                    WorkstreamUserRoleName = ow.WorkloadGroupVersion != null ? entities.WorkloadGroupUsers.FirstOrDefault(y => y.WorkloadGroupId == ow.WorkloadGroupVersion.WorkloadGroup.WorkloadGroupId && y.UserId == userId).Role.RoleName : string.Empty
                }).ToList();
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong with DefaultIfNull() not sure.

Comment: imho, one of the property of Microsoft.OneEstimator.DataAccess.Entities.AccessRights should be Int32? and not Int32.

Comment: I verified the data pulled from data. It is valid data and the problem is happening only when we are running performance test and user count is more than 40.